# How to invoke a function using dlsym(), if i am unaware about return type and parameters?

Tags: c++, c, linux, dlopen, dlsym

I have to invoke a function in external library whose type and number of parameters and return type is not known. How can i invoke that function in c++ using dlsym?

EDIT: How can i invoke function using dlsym(), if i get the return type and data type of  parameters as a string.

eg: client sends the func name , return type and parameter data types to the server. server dynamically loads corresponding so using dlopen(). Now how can i invoke the func using dlsym?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't know anything about it, why do you think you need to call it?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reinvent ffi (foreign function interface). There are a few such libraries around for various programming languages and with various licences. You might want to look at our even use one of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **known number of combinations of parameters and their types** that might be passed to the function in question you could implement a call according to this info and during run-time parse the string containing the types and order of the parameters to be passed and then jump to the implementation of the appropriate call.

If you do **not know in advance the possible types and orders of parameters** to be passed to the function in question, there is no possibility to call it.

C does not do ad hoc compilation, so each call's parameters and their types need to be know at compile time, that is when the executable is build.

Comment: "during run-time parse the string containing the types and order of the parameters to be passed and then jump to the implementation of the appropriate call." I dont know how to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

> How to invoke a function using dlsym(), if i am unaware about return type and parameters?

Then you can't. If you try to guess those, then invoking a function through a pointer to incompatible function type will result in undefined behavior.